# How to open new terminal and run command in the new terminal using python

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to open new terminal and run command in the new terminal using python

Here is my code :

```
cmd="""open -a Terminal "`pwd`" """
    os.popen(cmd)
    command="cmd"
    output=os.popen(command)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On OSX You can use something like this:

script content:

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "ls"
end tell'
```

and call it from inside python script by:

```
subprocess.call("/path/to/script.sh")
```